# How to extend scope to an exec'd function?

Tags: python, python-import, python-exec

I have a module object containing several function definitions.  Here is a simplified example.

The source code (makes up the module "my_module")

```py
def functionA():
    print("hello")

def functionB():
    functionA()
    print("world")
```

The module is built with imp (I know it is depreciated, but my app is still on python 3.5)

```py
ast_node = parse(source)
byte_code = compile(ast_node, 'my_module', 'exec')
my_module = imp.new_module('my_module')
exec(byte_code, __builtins__, my_module.__dict__)
```

I am trying to run `functionB()` using `exec` and passing in the full module `__dict__` as the local dictionary.  (I've also tried passing it in as the global dictionary without any luck)

```py
exec("functionB()", None, my_module.__dict__)
```

The error I see is `NameError: name 'functionA' is not defined`

Is it possible to extend the local (or even global) scope to the executing function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "extend scope". Your problem is that you're doing things in the wrong namespaces. When you execute the module's code:

```
exec(byte_code, __builtins__, my_module.__dict__)
```

you're doing that with the built-ins namespace as globals, when you should be using the module's namespace as globals:

```
exec(byte_code, my_module.__dict__)
```

Then the module's functions will have the correct global namespace. Currently, they're all using the built-ins namespace as their global namespace.

Also, don't use `__builtins__` for the built-ins namespace. It's an implementation detail, and it doesn't even work the way you think - its value is different in different contexts. Sometimes it's set to the `builtins` module itself, rather than that module's dict. Instead, `import builtins` and use `builtins.__dict__` if you need the built-ins dict.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand now.  I hadn't stopped to think the issue was with the module creation.  I was fixated on the execution of the function call.